# Authentication Error In TFS Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins, azure-devops

I am trying to setup jenkins to get latest and deploy a solution from VS Online. 
I have set up the TFS Plugin and gave the necessary values as in the online step by step tutorials .

However , when I am building, I am getting the following error.

TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://myproject.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.
FATAL: Executable returned an unexpected result code [100]
ERROR: null

Alternate credentials in VS Online do not work as well.
Please let me know if u need any other information from my side as I am new to CI and maynot know wverything about it. Thanks